# Populate data in recyclerView matching with key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this activity DataSaveActivity which is called from a qrScan activity. DataSaveActivity is called after qrScan scans QR code and return a string value (which is a unique key generated by firebase of pushed data) to DataSaveActivity.  What I need to do is to display the data matching with the keyValue inside recycler view.
This is my DataSaveActivity

```
public class DataSaveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String keyValue;
private RecyclerView mReceipt;
private DatabaseReference mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_save);
    mReceipt = new RecyclerView(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent == null) {
        keyValue = null;
    } else {
        keyValue = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    }
// HERE ITS DISPLAYING ALL THE DATA INSIDE BILLS 
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bills");
//.child(keyValue); WHEN I AM ADDING THIS AFTER .child("Bills")IT CRASHES.
    mReceipt = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.othersRecycler);
    mReceipt.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ReceiptViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ReceiptViewHolder>
            (DataModel.class, R.layout.reciept_row, ReceiptViewHolder.class, mRef){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ReceiptViewHolder viewHolder,DataModel model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setBillNo("Bill No : " + model.getBillNo());
            viewHolder.setStoreName("Store Name : " + model.getCompany());
            viewHolder.setDate("Date : " + model.getDate());
            viewHolder.setTime("Time : " + model.getTime());
            viewHolder.setBillTotal("Total : " + model.getTotal());

        }
    };
    mReceipt.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
public static class ReceiptViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    public ReceiptViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setBillNo(String billNo){
        TextView BillNo = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptBillNo);
        BillNo.setText(billNo);
    }
    public void setStoreName(String company){
        TextView StoreName = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptStoreName);
        StoreName.setText(company);
    }
    public void setDate(String date){
        TextView Date = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptDate);
        Date.setText(date);
    }
    public void setTime(String time){
        TextView Time = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptTime);
        Time.setText(time);
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone){
        TextView Phone = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptPhone);
        Phone.setText(phone);
    }
    public void setBillTotal(String total){
        TextView BillTotal = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.receiptTotal);
        BillTotal.setText(total);
    }

}
}
```

Structure of my Firebase database is like this:

[image: structure firebase]

I want to display data of the key(keyValue) sent from the qrScan activity.

Answer (score 0):

First make the `firebaseListAdapter` variable global.

```
private FirebaseListAdapter<Users> firebaseListAdapter;
```

Then just remove `FirebaseListAdapter<Users>` where you intialize the adapter.

So in order to solve this, you need to override the `onStart()` method and add the following line of code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseListAdapter.startListening();
}
```

Comment: do you mean making firebaseRecyclerAdapter  variable global??

Comment: It means that you need to declare it at the begging of your class, to be seen everywhere in your activity class.

Comment: I am not sure but, I think I have to retrieve data using onChildEventListener() method.

Comment: says cannot resolve method startlistening. I do not have any list view. Its all of the code I have inside dataSaveActivity

Comment: Have you declared that variable as global?

Comment: In this case I recommend you use the last [version](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) in which you need to use `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`. Give it a try, is the best solution. And obviously, use my answer. Will solve your problem.

Comment: when I am adding .child(keyValue) inside database reference, it crashes with error **com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type project_name.DataModel**

Comment: Using the same last version or the same version? Update your question with the new code.